# Using CSS to display dropdown menu horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a horizontal list in a web part in SharePoint. I've gone over this code over and over and can't find the issue. For some reason, the list still displays vertically. Any ideas?

CSS

```
ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ffffff no-repeat center;
    }
    ul li{
        display:inline-block;
        float: left;    padding: 25px 25px 0 125px;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 25px;    font-weight: bold;  color: #FFFFFF; 
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        color: #FFF;    padding: 10px 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{

    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 150px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
        float: left;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: inline;    /* Display the dropdown */
        background: #FFFFFF;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

HTML List (still in progress; just testing before I fix all the text/links)

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Current Performance &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Grafenwoehr</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hohenfels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Katterbach</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Stuttgart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vilseck</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I haven't done this stuff in years but my boss wants me to try and make this work. -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ul.dropdown` does float horizontally, but its `width` forces the elements to order vertically. To test this out you can set its `min-width` to something like 900px: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jed3r4ut/)

As your `ul.dropdown` is a child of its parent `li`, which is set to `display: inline-block; position: relative;`, its bound to its borders using `width: 100%`.

To solve this problem you can remove `position: relative` of your `li` elements to remove this border. Now its `width: 100%` relates to your `body`.

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jed3r4ut/3/)

Comment: So simple, yet I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have a dropdown here

```
ul li ul.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
}
```

which has a 100% width relative to

```
ul li {
    position: relative; 
}
```

which is the culprit here. Removing the "Position:relative" above fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:block` on the `UL.dropdown` and `display:inline-block` on the `UL.dropdown LI`.

Comment: `display:block` on `ul.dropdown` leaves the dropdown list always visible.

`display:block` on `li: hover ul.dropdown` and `display:inline-block` on `ul.dropdown li` still has the list show up as vertical. :\

Answer (score 0):

just remove (position: relative;) from "ul li" list will come horizontally. 
code will be like:

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;    
    padding: 25px 25px 0 125px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;    
    font-weight: bold;  color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

just replace this code with yours.
Thank You